# Jordan canonical form with more than 1 eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form

I need to solve: $$ v'=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
5 & -1 & -2\\
-4 & 5 & 4\\
4 & -2 & -1
\end{array}\right)v $$
After finding the characteristic polynomial and finding the eigenvectors I found
$$ p(A)=(x-3)^3,ker(A-3I)=span\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
0
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\} $$
Now I want to find the Jordan chains and I'm struggling a bit.
$$ \left.\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & -2\\
-4 & 2 & 4\\
4 & -2 & -4
\end{array}\right|\begin{array}{c}
\alpha+\beta\\
2\alpha\\
\beta
\end{array}\xrightarrow[2R_{1}-R_{3}\to R_{3}]{\substack{2R_{1}+R_{2}\to R_{2}}
}\left.\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & -2\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right|\begin{array}{c}
\alpha+\beta\\
4\alpha+2\beta\\
2\alpha+\beta
\end{array}\Rightarrow\beta=-2\alpha $$
After that I took $ \alpha =1,\beta =-2 $ and tried continuing the chain with
$$\left.\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & -2\\
-4 & 2 & 4\\
4 & -2 & -4
\end{array}\right|\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
2\\
-2
\end{array}\Rightarrow2x-y-2z=-1\Rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right) $$
After doing this, I cant keep my chain as the 3rd vector I need has no solution:
$$ \left.\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -1 & -2\\
-4 & 2 & 4\\
4 & -2 & -4
\end{array}\right|\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\Rightarrow \text{no solution} $$
How do I fix it and reach the Jordan form? I know how to make it work when I have only 1 eigenvector but I can't find examples for this case.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a third vector, you have:
$$ker(A-3I)=span\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
0
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\}=span\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
2\\
-2
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\}$$
so we can have
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&2&1\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&3&1\\
0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&2&1\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
so, for your differential equation
$$e^{tA}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&2&1\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}
e^{t\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&3&1\\
0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&2&1\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} =\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&2&1\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}
{\begin{pmatrix}
e^{3t}&0&0\\
0&e^{3t}&e^{3t}t\\
0&0&e^{3t}
\end{pmatrix}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&2&1\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{3t}(2t+1)&-e^{3t}t&-2e^{3t}t\\
-4e^{3t}t&e^{3t}(2t+1)&4e^{3t}t\\
4e^{3t}t&-2e^{3t}t&e^{3t}(1-4t)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Mind explaining how you got the $ \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right) $ vector? 
You could just as likely take the other vector $ \left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
0
\end{array}\right) $ ?

Comment: Yes you could, it’s arbitrary, any linearly independent eigenvector would do, they just need to span the eigenspace.